# Absolute positioned span automatically gets pushed off the webpage

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-position, removing-whitespace

This is the third part of a single page website, each one taking up total viewport height and width. The span elements in div 'gun' are appearing pushed down in Firefox browser, creating a whitespace while it looks all perfectly fine in Edge. I presume this is because of the relative and absolute positioning (this was mentioned in answer to several whitespace issues) but I have no idea how to fix it.

Here's the HTML of only that part of the page (the 'end' div is sort of wrapper for the entire third section of the website):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* Firefox */
}


/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}


/*Ending */

.end {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}


/* Gun and company */

.gun img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 38%;
  height: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
  transform: rotate(75deg) translate(20rem, -24.5rem);
  filter: sepia(0.8);
}

.gun-shadow {
  position: absolute;
  top: 32rem;
  left: 46rem;
  width: 100px;
  /*80 px, probably*/
  height: 370px;
  /*385px*/
  background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #ffbebe, #fffaf0);
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.gun-shadow2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 34.3rem;
  left: 46.5rem;
  width: 80px;
  /*60px*/
  height: 285px;
  /*300px*/
  background-color: #202b3a;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.spotlight {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5.8rem;
  left: 32.75rem;
  width: 530px;
  height: 600px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-0deg, #202b3a, transparent);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 63.85% 150%, 33.35% 150%);
  /* polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 20% 100%) */
  opacity: 0.4;
}

.gun-shadow2::after {
  width: 80px;
  height: 285px;
  background: fuchsia;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="end">
  <div class="gun">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/07/13/11/52/pistol-158868_960_720.png" alt="the gun">
    <span class="gun-shadow"></span>
    <span class="gun-shadow2"></span>
    <span class="spotlight"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="social-icons1">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-at"></a><span class=" content content1">Click to Email</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-envelope-open"></a><span class=" content content2">We do have a mailbox</span>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-phone"></a><span class=" content content3">Call us maybe</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The code might have several issues. Please let me know if you need any other information in understanding the situation. Thank you.

Edge Version:
[image: Webpage without whitespace]

Firefox Version:
[image: Webpage with whitespace in the bottom]

Comment: I see you're using relative units to position absolute elements. You'll more often end up with unexpected behaviour and side effects with elements positioned outside of the normal document flow when you do this. If I need an element to be positioned in the bottom right corner of a containing element I'd use absolute units of measure (px)  and position them `right` and `bottom` rather than `top` and `left`. Your elements will always be positioned relative and responsively to the containing element this way. For good measure I'd consider adding an overflow on the containing element as well.

Comment: Could you put up an image of what it's supposed to look like as I seem to be seeing (nearly) the same on Edge and FF, though have to go F11 full screen on Edge to see anything at the bottom. And I see no fuschia.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Thank you for the explanation. I am just a bit confused as to how do I add overflow on the containing element. Can you please point it out in my code here, if it's possible? Either way, thanks again!

Comment: @AHaworth I've added two screenshots for the the browsers. And I 'fuschia' is actually name of the colour in the background. I add them for easy use instead of hex code (because then I'd have to look up hex codes), so yeah. Thank you for taking a look at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quickest fix can be reducing `2rem` from `top` property in `.gun-shadow` , `.gun-shadow2` and `.spotlight`.

Another way is to change `top` property to `bottom` property and give it a number to position it where ever you want.
Try this styles:

```
.gun-shadow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -128px;
    left: 46rem;
    width: 100px;
    /*80 px, probably*/
    height: 370px;
    /*385px*/
    background-image: linear-gradient(-90deg, #ffbebe, #fffaf0);
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.gun-shadow2 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -85px;
    left: 46.5rem;
    width: 80px;
    /*60px*/
    height: 285px;
    /*300px*/
    background-color: #202b3a;
    border-radius: 100%;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.spotlight {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 61px;
    left: 32.75rem;
    width: 530px;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(-0deg, #202b3a, transparent);
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 63.85% 150%, 33.35% 150%);
    /* polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 80% 100%, 20% 100%) */
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

***A very Important thing is to use absolute units like px rather than rem***

Comment: Okay, this worked real smooth! Thank you so much—I simply replaced my code with yours. And as for rem and px, I think I saw it in a YT video that rem is much—flexible, I guess—measurement than px. That's why I kept using it everywhere. Thank you for that tip and answer as well!

Comment: Happy to help and thank you for your kind words.